# PHP loop through two different arrays with the same name

Tags: php

I'm quite new to PHP. Anyone knows how to loop through two different arrays with the same name? There's first array `$test[$i]` that values start with `"zX" (zX122, xZ1200, etc.)` and second array `$test[$i]` that values start with `"X" (X122, X1200 etc.)`. Main thing my function does is to check if some value is in interval `zX1/zX9 (X1/X9) - zX1200/zX9200 (X1200/X9200)`. And I don't have a clue how to perform a correct double loop like "values that starts with `zX OR X`". Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
$test=array();

for ($i=0; $i<201;$i++){
    $test[$i] = "zX".strval($i);
    $test[$i] = "X".strval($i);
}

$test[201] = "zX1";
$test[202] = "zX2";
$test[203] = "zX3";
$test[204] = "zX4";
$test[205] = "zX5";
$test[206] = "zX6";
$test[207] = "zX7";
$test[208] = "zX8";
$test[209] = "zX9";
$test[211] = "X1";
$test[212] = "X2";
$test[213] = "X3";
$test[214] = "X4";
$test[215] = "X5";
$test[216] = "X6";
$test[217] = "X7";
$test[218] = "X8";
$test[219] = "X9";
```

Comment: Unless you know specifically the indices you want to check within the array, you have no choice but to loop through the entire thing and check both conditions.  This also not "two different" arrays, its one single array.

Comment: So I have to join them both, right? $test1 + $test2 = $test and then loop?

Comment: Where are you getting test1 and test2? Your code only shows me one array, not two.

Comment: What if I rename those arrays?

Comment: You keep saying "two", "both" and "those" but you only have _one single array_ in your code. Variables names are unique identifiers. Reusing the same variable name will only overwrite the existing.

Answer (score 1):

You have a fundamental coding problem here, the same variable can not represent two arrays the way you have it laid out, the second instance of $test[i] is currently overwriting the first.

```
    $test[$i] = "zX".strval($i); // $test[i] = "zX1"
    $test[$i] = "X".strval($i); // $test[i] = "X1"
    // $test[$i] can never be "zX".strval($i);
```

You would need to change the breakdown to something like this

```
    $test[$i][] = "zX".strval($i); // array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "zX0" } }
    $test[$i][] = "X".strval($i); // array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "zX0" [1]=> string(2) "X0" } }
```

this would allow you to loop through the array of each index to get their values something like this but this is also not the greatest scaleable option either, it would be better to separate out each of the "zX" and "x" into their own arrays.

```
// initially loop through the array and getting all its keys
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
    // Loop through each index of test and find each value
    foreach ($test[$key] as $item) {
        var_dump($item); //string(3) "zX0"
    }
}
```